# How to make the Amount(i-e Price) dynamic while intergrating BuyNow Paypal button

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, paypal, payment

I am working on VB.Net Basically I want to make the amount to be dynamic like if the total cost is $50 then in Paypal payment page $50 should appear.

All the values are coming dynamic like Quantity but the only problem I am facing is in the amount. Amount is not getting changed.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Just to clarify - you REALLY need to include the code that is relevant to this post. Without code, we can't help at all. Any answers would be guesses.